# Can't compile PHP 7.2.2 with OpenSSL 1.1.0g

Tags: linux, php, openssl, make

So i'll get to the point.

I want to compile PHP 7.2.2 on my Raspberry Pi (v1) with OpenSSL support. I have OpenSSL 1.1.0g installed with i compiled.

Output from uname -a:

```
Linux 4.4.50+ #1 Tue Mar 7 15:10:58 UTC 2017 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

(i've only deleted from it my hostname)

My ./configure command that i use:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-openssl=/usr/local --enable-mbstring --with-imap --with-imap-ssl --with-kerberos --with-pdo-mysql --with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

And finnaly when i run make it gives my this errors:

```
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zm_startup_openssl':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:1434: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zm_info_openssl':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:1588: undefined reference to `OpenSSL_version'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `php_openssl_asn1_time_to_time_t':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:938: undefined reference to `ASN1_STRING_get0_data'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:953: undefined reference to `ASN1_STRING_get0_data'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:953: undefined reference to `ASN1_STRING_get0_data'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_pop':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_pop'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_free':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `php_openssl_is_private_key':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4086: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_EC_KEY'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4049: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_DSA'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4053: undefined reference to `DSA_get0_pqg'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4058: undefined reference to `DSA_get0_key'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4067: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_DH'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4071: undefined reference to `DH_get0_pqg'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4076: undefined reference to `DH_get0_key'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4032: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4036: undefined reference to `RSA_get0_factors'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_spki_export_challenge':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:2070: undefined reference to `ASN1_STRING_get0_data'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `php_openssl_add_assoc_name_entry':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:874: undefined reference to `ASN1_STRING_get0_data'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_x509_parse':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:2335: undefined reference to `X509_get_version'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:2362: undefined reference to `X509_getm_notBefore'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:2363: undefined reference to `X509_getm_notAfter'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:2365: undefined reference to `X509_getm_notBefore'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:2366: undefined reference to `X509_getm_notAfter'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:2373: undefined reference to `X509_get_signature_nid'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_GENERAL_NAME_pop_free':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509v3.h:165: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_pop_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_GENERAL_NAME_num':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509v3.h:165: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_GENERAL_NAME_value':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509v3.h:165: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `openssl_x509v3_subjectAltName':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:2265: undefined reference to `ASN1_STRING_get0_data'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_new_null':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_new_null'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_free':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_INFO_free':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:252: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_INFO_shift':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:252: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_shift'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_push':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_push'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_INFO_num':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:252: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_num':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_free':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_free'
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_free'
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_pop_free':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_pop_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_new_null':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_new_null'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_push':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_push'
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_push'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_num':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_pop':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_pop'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_free':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_csr_get_subject':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3616: undefined reference to `X509_REQ_get_subject_name'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_pkey_get_details':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4799: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_DH'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4806: undefined reference to `DH_get0_pqg'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4807: undefined reference to `DH_get0_key'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4821: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_EC_KEY'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4830: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_EC_KEY'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4777: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_DSA'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4784: undefined reference to `DSA_get0_pqg'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4785: undefined reference to `DSA_get0_key'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4748: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4755: undefined reference to `RSA_get0_key'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4756: undefined reference to `RSA_get0_factors'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4757: undefined reference to `RSA_get0_crt_params'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4866: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_EC_KEY'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_dh_compute_key':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4909: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_DH'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_free':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_value':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_num':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_free':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_new_null':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_new_null'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_push':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_push'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_pop_free':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_pop_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_push':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_push'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_num':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_value':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_CRL_num':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:226: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_CRL_value':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:226: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_X509_pop_free':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_pop_free'
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_pop_free'
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_pop_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_private_encrypt':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:5611: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_private_decrypt':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:5673: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_public_encrypt':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:5741: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_public_decrypt':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:5804: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_RSA'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_sign':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:5912: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_new'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:5927: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_verify':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:5979: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_new'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:5986: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_seal':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:6073: undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_reset'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_digest':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:6304: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_new'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:6327: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_free'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_encrypt':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:6623: undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_reset'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_decrypt':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:6710: undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_reset'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_CONF_VALUE_num':
/usr/local/include/openssl/conf.h:31: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_CONF_VALUE_value':
/usr/local/include/openssl/conf.h:31: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_csr_sign':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3447: undefined reference to `X509_REQ_get_subject_name'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3456: undefined reference to `X509_getm_notBefore'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3457: undefined reference to `X509_getm_notAfter'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `php_openssl_make_REQ':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3084: undefined reference to `X509_REQ_get_subject_name'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_CONF_VALUE_num':
/usr/local/include/openssl/conf.h:31: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_CONF_VALUE_value':
/usr/local/include/openssl/conf.h:31: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_CONF_VALUE_num':
/usr/local/include/openssl/conf.h:31: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
/usr/local/include/openssl/conf.h:31: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `sk_CONF_VALUE_value':
/usr/local/include/openssl/conf.h:31: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `php_openssl_pkey_init_and_assign_rsa':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4133: undefined reference to `RSA_set0_key'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `php_openssl_pkey_init_dsa':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4167: undefined reference to `DSA_set0_pqg'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4186: undefined reference to `DSA_get0_key'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4187: undefined reference to `BN_is_zero'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `php_openssl_pkey_init_dh':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4244: undefined reference to `DH_set0_pqg'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `php_openssl_pkey_init_and_assign_rsa':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4146: undefined reference to `RSA_set0_crt_params'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4139: undefined reference to `RSA_set0_factors'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `php_openssl_pkey_init_dsa':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4174: undefined reference to `DSA_set0_key'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `php_openssl_dh_pub_from_priv':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4221: undefined reference to `BN_with_flags'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `php_openssl_pkey_init_dh':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4258: undefined reference to `DH_set0_key'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4251: undefined reference to `DH_set0_key'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_pkey_export_to_file':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4536: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_EC_KEY'
ext/openssl/.libs/openssl.o: In function `zif_openssl_pkey_export':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/openssl.c:4613: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_EC_KEY'
ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `php_openssl_create_sni_server_ctx':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1321: undefined reference to `TLS_server_method'
ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `sk_X509_num':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `sk_X509_value':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value'
ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `sk_X509_num':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509.h:97: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `php_openssl_setup_crypto':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1571: undefined reference to `TLS_client_method'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1625: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_security_level'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1651: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_alpn_select_cb'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1666: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_options'
ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `php_openssl_set_server_specific_opts':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1252: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_get_options'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1279: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_options'
ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `php_openssl_setup_crypto':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1571: undefined reference to `TLS_server_method'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:1647: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_alpn_protos'
ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `php_openssl_sockop_set_option':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:2365: undefined reference to `SSL_get0_alpn_selected'
ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `sk_GENERAL_NAME_num':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509v3.h:165: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_num'
ext/openssl/.libs/xp_ssl.o: In function `sk_GENERAL_NAME_value':
/usr/local/include/openssl/x509v3.h:165: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_sk_value'
ext/phar/.libs/util.o: In function `phar_verify_signature':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/phar/util.c:1563: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_new'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/phar/util.c:1595: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_free'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/phar/util.c:1586: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_free'
ext/phar/.libs/util.o: In function `phar_create_signature':
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/phar/util.c:1860: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_new'
/home/pi/php-7.2.2/ext/phar/util.c:1892: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:273: recipe for target 'sapi/cli/php' failed
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

It's very long! The `evp.h` is where it should be and i even linked the `/usr/local/include/openssl/` directory to `/usr/include/openssl`.

I have successfully complied PHP 7.2.2 but whitout OpenSSL support (`./configure' '--prefix=/usr/`)

I have you know that i was trying everything that i could find on the internet for past few days.

So any ideas how to fix this? (and please don't tell my that i have to reinstall my OpenSSL because want to stay with 1.1.0g)

Comment: Hi, do u remember how you fixed that bug, I am facing similar